# How to directly add and call a brief unit test in Solution class of LeetCode

Tags: c++, unit-testing, class

I was training myself to write brief unit tests while solving leetcode questions. However, I couldn't call the unit test I wrote in the notepad on Leetcode website directly.(I understand the most formal way to write unit tests is to create another test class in a test file. However, I just want to quickly warm up on this, so I put it in the same class as Solution.) I'm wondering whether I messed something wrong with the syntax of creating an object or it's due to some hidden structure in the Leetcode?

For example, for Leetcode question 2400, I tried to invoke my `testNumberofWays`
as:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numberOfWays(int startPos, int endPos, int k) {
        int waysTable[2000][1001] = {{0}};
        if((k - abs(endPos-startPos))%2 != 0){
            return 0;
        }
        waysTable[1000][0]=1;
        // omit some implementation for simplicity
        return waysTable[abs(endPos-startPos+1000)][k];
    }
  
    void testNumberOfWays(){
        Solution solu = Solution();
        assert(solu.numberOfWays(1, 2, 3) == 3); 
    }
};

Solution *s = new Solution();
s->testNumberofWays();
```

However I got the error message as

```
Line 33: Char 1: error: unknown type name 's'
s->testNumberofWays();
^
```

And I've also tried to write a static function out of Solution class directly like this

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numberOfWays(int startPos, int endPos, int k) {
        int waysTable[2000][1001] = {{0}};
        //omit some implementation for simplicity
        return waysTable[abs(endPos-startPos+1000)][k];
    }
};


static void testNumberOfWays(){
    Solution solu = Solution();
    assert(solu.numberOfWays(1, 2, 3) == 3);
    return;
}

testNumberOfWays();
```

But I got error message as this:

```
Line 39: Char 1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
testNumberOfWays();
^
1 error generated.
```

Please let me know if the ways above may be achievable on Leetcode. Any help on how to write and run some quick unit tests on the notepad of Leetcode would be super helpful!

Comment: I'd suggest to use [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) and put your last two lines in a `main()` function

Comment: Also leetcode questions could let you write your own test cases in the bottome of the screen, so I'm not sure why you need to write test cases elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by `on the notepad of Leetcode`.
if you want to test Leetcode in a local environment, you may want try [this](https://github.com/KargathEx/leetcode-parser).
it can translate test cases into corresponding data structures, and you only need to execute `Solution().func()` in the main function. .